# boot2docker command works on shell, but not in script

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, docker, boot2docker

New to docker here.  I have a series of commands which, if fire them off on the shell, work just fine, but if I put them in a script, don't.

```
boot2docker destroy
boot2docker init
boot2docker start
boot2docker ssh &
host=$(boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null)
# everything works fine up to here
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_boot2docker -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" docker@$host docker run --net=host my-image
```

If I don't try to run a command via ssh, everything works.  Viz:

`ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_boot2docker -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" docker@$host`

This brings up the docker ssh prompt.  But if I do run the command via the script (and this is what I actually need to do) I get the error message:

`level="fatal" msg="Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?"`

Again, if I just enter that last command, or the whole litany of commands, into the shell, no problems.  How can I make this script work?

Thanks

**update**
If I put that last line in its own script, and run the two scripts in sequence from the command line, everything is fine (same as just typing all the commands in sequence.)  If I chain the scripts, or create a third to run them in sequence, I get the error.  What am I to make of this?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it would be a lot more helpful if, instead of downvoting, you answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

`host` probably isn't defined when you try to use it. You can probably confirm that by `echo`ing it's value before running `ssh`. Easiest solution would be to put these two lines together in the same file:

```
host=$(boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null)
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_boot2docker -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" docker@$host docker run --net=host my-image
```